# memory leak in c

Tags: c++, c

will the following code result in memory leak

```
char * a()
{
   char * b = malloc(100);
   return b;
 }

B()
{ 
  char * c = a();
  free (c);
}
```

Comment: @GMan: you should have pointed out that the second function needs to be declared with a return type, i.e. `void B()`. "This isn't valid C++" possibly doesn't help the OP at all. ;)

Comment: @frast:  The word "no" answers the question, takes fewer letters and makes you look less unfriendly than "please read a book".

Comment: @JeremyP You are right it was unfriendly. I knew someone would answer his question, but sometimes it is better to self study as far as possible and then ask questions which are less obvious.

Answer (score 10):

No. You're  freeing the allocated memory after all. The general rule is, if you're calling `free()` for each `malloc()` function call, then that means you're not leaking memory.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You are allocating memory inside a(), returning a pointer to that memory, which you're freeing in B().

Answer (score 2):

In the function B(), it will definitely NOT cause a memory leak because you are calling free. But It WILL cause a memory leak if you call a() without calling free, so in case you are getting some memory leaks and wondering why it is happening, then look somewhere else where you are calling the function a() without calling free() after that.

Answer (score 0):

No. You allocate the memory, then free the memory at the same address (even if the pointer that contains that address has been copied around).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so... Why do you think it could result in a leak?
The memory you allocate is the same that you free.

Answer (score 0):

It will not leak memory. Your function a() is returning the address of memory location to function b() which is being freed. Do not get confused with allocation and de-allcation of memory in different functions. It will work fine since memory you are allocating is on heap which is common area for both functions e.i. a() & b() (as far as they are in same address space).